# Using JOIN TOOL in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

[image: model]

I want to perform JOIN TOOL for all DBFs generated from ZONAL STATISTICS AS TABLE into one table. However, it seems that DBF has a maximum of 255 fields while my dataset has more than 500 fields/columns. So, my question is how can I divide/separate the INPUT FOLDER such that ZONAL STATISTICS will perform 250 tables at a time? All else is working other than this issue. I am using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Why not just use a geodatabase instead of shapefiles, and avoid all the limitations of shapefiles all together?

Comment: what do you mean by gdb? i am not sure i can follow your suggestion. do you mean i convert which part of this model to gdb?

Comment: You are striking dBase limits due to using shapefile format for your data - if you use file geodatabase feature classes in general any limits will be higher or non-existent - and performance should be better.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your patience. Your suggestions on creating file gdb worked in the model. It ran successfully!